# How to query PostgreSQL for all records where hstore is empty?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to query my PostgreSQL table for all rows that have an empty hstore. It must be obvious to all but me, as I can't find any documentation on how to do it nor other StackOverflow questions answering the question. Checking for NULL isn't helpful, as I get back all rows, even those rows where `properties` has no keys/values:

```
SELECT widgets.* 
FROM "widgets" 
WHERE properties IS NOT NULL
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to return all keys of the column as an array and check if that array is not empty:

```
SELECT *
FROM widgets
WHERE properties IS NOT NULL
  AND array_length(akeys(properties),1) > 0;
```

Comment: gives me error with postgresql 9.3
`ERROR:  function akeys(character varying) does not exist`

Comment: @SandipPingle: did you install the [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html) extension?

Answer (score 6):

A simpler way of doing this as per a [message on the PostgreSQL listerve](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAL_0b1vDrXFiQtQTfffwSnPoj_K0c+zHQ27=bxnQE9PaxXRHNg@mail.gmail.com) is:

```
SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE properties = ''::HSTORE;
```

### an aside:

As a general rule, I would recommend that you don't have a column which can be *empty* sometimes and `NULL` other times, outside of distinct cases where you want a semantic difference there, e.g. for an application that interprets the two differently. Especially for `BOOLEAN` columns, I generally choose to prevent this extra degree of freedom.

I often do something do something similar to:

```
ALTER TABLE widgets ALTER COLUMN properties SET NOT NULL;
-- OR:
ALTER TABLE widgets ADD CONSTRAINT its_null_or_nothin CHECK ( properties <> ''::HSTORE );
```

Depending on what you find easier to remember, you can also create an empty hstore via `hstore('{}'::TEXT[])`.